# Runing hive query in Spark to retrieve elements below median values

Tags: hive

I need to write a hive query in Spark application to retrieve all rows which one of its particular column is bellow than the median of that column.

```
dataFrame.registerTempTable("df")
val hiveTest=hiveContext.sql("SELECT * from df where ts < percentile(cast(ts as LONG), 0.5))")
System.out.print("The training set from hive is :")
```

But I get bellow error

```
17/05/05 14:22:38 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: SELECT * from df where ts < percentile(cast(ts as LONG), 0.5)
NoViableAltException(162@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.primitiveType(HiveParser.java:38886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.castExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:4336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.atomExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceFieldExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnaryPrefixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6768)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnarySuffixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6828)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseXorExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceStarExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedencePlusExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAmpersandExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7634)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.expression(HiveParser.java:45846)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectExpression(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:3755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectExpression(HiveParser.java:45837)
```

I am not sure what is the correct hive query for above?

Answer (score 0):

cast(ts as LONG) doesn't work,  use cast(ts as Bigint)